# Not able to click and drag in Windows Explorer

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, mouse

I am not able to click and drag in **Windows Explorer** specifically. I am able to click and drag in any other program. I tested in a VM that I had to make sure that it was not the mouse and it dragged fine to select items in the Desktop and folders. The issue is not the mouse but the OS. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you restarted and does the issue persist across restart? I have found this behavior can be related to Antivirus Software malfunctioning. I have observed it with Norton and McAfee business-level antivirus products. Generally a reboot resolves this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the problem by going in the **Registry** and editing the following entries and rebooting the computer:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop]
"DragHeight"="4"
"DragWidth"="4"
```